# Compare numerically in varchar column

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, function, hql

I need to write HQL query (not native SQL if possible) on PostgreSQL db that selects the rows that have `attr` value greater than 39. The problem is that `attr` column is a varchar column and contains not only numbers. I need only the numbers and only greater than 39. Native query that works for me is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE attr ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' AND CAST(attr AS BIGINT) > 39;
```

I tried following HQL equivalents (none  of which works):

```
1. SELECT myTable FROM MyTable myTable WHERE attr ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' AND CAST(attr AS long) > 39; //~ cannot be used in HQL query
2. SELECT myTable FROM MyTable myTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(attr) = 1 AND CAST(attr AS long) > 39; //cannot extract result set
3. SELECT myTable FROM MyTable myTable WHERE attr LIKE '^[0-9\.]+$' AND CAST(attr AS long) > 39; //cannot extract result set
4. SELECT myTable FROM MyTable myTable WHERE CAST(attr AS long) > 39; //cannot extract result set
5. SELECT myTable FROM MyTable myTable WHERE attr > '39'; //wrong data types - rows with 4 in the attr column are found
```

Comment: FYI on the pure postgres side, the conditions in your `WHERE` clause do not need to be evaluated in the order your wrote them in, so it's possible for your cast to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a PostgreSQL function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parse_attr_to_boolean(attr character varying) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
        BEGIN
                RETURN attr ~ '^[0-9\.]+$' AND CAST(attr AS BIGINT) > 39;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, you can just call the function in your HQL query:

```
SELECT t 
FROM MyTable t 
WHERE parse_attr_to_boolean(t.attr)
```

You only need to register the SQL function, like [`parse_attr_to_boolean`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/), if the function is used in the SELECT clause. However, since you are using it in the WHERE clause, it can just be passed as-is to the SQL query.

Comment: Nice trick. Of course, if this is an option, then why bother using JPQL at all, instead of going for native SQL :)

Comment: If you want to select entities, then it's going to be easier using JPQL than SQL, especially if you are using custom types (e.g. JSON, ARRAY, range, inet). For DTO projections, there is not much you gain using JPQL, hence the SQL alternative makes more sense.

Comment: When you `select *`, it should be possible to use `EntityManager#createNativeQuery(String, Class)` to map the results of a SQL query to entities, right?

Comment: That works more or less, depending on the underlying ResultSet type mapping. Unfortunately, there is no programmatic way to do the mapping at query time, leaving you only with the `@SqlResultSetMapping`, which is not very convenient.

Comment: It worked well for me in simple test cases, if I made sure that the columns I was selecting match the columns of the entities, without any result set mapping.

Comment: Yes, in simple cases it works fine. However, there are some use cases where it does not work right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply this trick:

```sql
SUBSTRING(
  CONCAT('00000000000000000000', attr), 
  LENGTH(attr) + 1, 
  20
) > '00000000000000000039'
```

I used a random number of 20 `0` digits. If you have bigger numbers in `attr`, you need to adapt. This doesn't take care of `attr` potentially matching string data, but I'm sure you have some other column that helps you interpret the `attr` column content more robustly.

But of course, I would definitely recommend stop using the EAV anti pattern in the first place, and/or use appropriate data types...